# Ionic 2 Components Not Rendering

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm starting to build a new Ionic 2 app but not of the Ionic components will render correctly (e.g. select boxes, cards). I started the project using the Angular CLI and I'm using the sidebar template.

The HTML from one of my templates is here:

```
<ion-view view-title="Games">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>Console</ion-label>
                        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="consoleSelected" multiple="true">
                            <ion-option ng-repeat="console in consoles" value="nes">{{ console.Name }}</ion-option>
                        </ion-select>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-list-header>
                        Games
                    </ion-list-header>
                    <ion-item ng-repeat="game in games" href="#/app/game/{{game.ID}}">
                        {{ game.Title }}
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The ion-card, and ion-select components don't render like they should. I don't think the ion-view/content/grid and row components are rendering either but I can't really tell.

However, if I add the components using CSS classes:

```
 <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username">
        </label>
```

The components render correctly. The code from the first *incorrect* template is copied from the Ionic docs though.

I'm running the app using `ionic serve` and viewing it in Chrome. I've attached a screen shot of the first component as well.

Anybody know what I have to do to get them to render?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly** `ion-view` is an ionic 1 "component". It does not exist in Ionic >= 2.
Your template structure will be something like:

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
  <!-- title and buttons -->
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <!-- list items -->
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer><!-- optional>
 <ion-toolbar>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Relevant docs:

- [ion-header](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Header/)
- [ion-content](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/)
- [ion-footer](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Footer/)

**Secondly** you are mixing AngularJS and Angular >=2 syntax. Ionic 2 uses Angular 2 and Ionic 3.x uses Angular 4.
You should use [*ngFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngFor) instead of `ng-repeat`.

[Angular tutorial docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your comment "ion-view is an ionic 1 "component"" made me check if I had the correct version of Ionic installed because I'd copied that components from the example template.

Turns our I had accidently created an Ionic 1 project.